# Replacing a specified nvarchar string in database column with a carriage return in sql-ce

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

When not using the nvarchar and replacing with another string i.e.'test' I get the expected replacing results. I am attempting to insert a carriage return

```
private void reformatData(SqlCeConnection conn)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCeCommand comm = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE database " + "SET column = replace(MoodLog, '[ret]', nvarchar(13));", conn);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlCeException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any exception or error message?

Comment: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): The function is not recognized by SQL Server Compact. [ Name of function = nvarchar,Data type (if known) =  ]
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Program.reformatData(SqlCeConnection conn) in d:\SkyDrive\Visual Studio Projects\Program\program.cs:line 161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the nchar function, no nvarchar function with SQL Server Compact:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174852.aspx

Comment: is the integer value representing the carriage return the same for NCHAR?

Comment: I thought this might be the issue, as I feverishly tried CHAR, CHR, nvarchar, and varchar. Damn you NCHAR.....